# How to read data from topic using kafka-node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache-kafka, producer-consumer

I have topic that i have to read from kafka server so for that i just need to create consumer that can read data from kafka topic, I always get error topic does not exist.

1- How can i make sure kafka connection is established ?

2- How to get the data from specific topic in kafka ?

main.js

```
var kafka = require('kafka-node');
var config = require('./config.js');
var kafkaConn = config.kafkaCon.dit;
var HighLevelConsumer = kafka.HighLevelConsumer;
//var HighLevelProducer = kafka.HighLevelProducer;
var Client = kafka.Client;
var Offset = kafka.Offset;
var topics = [{topic: 'UEQ'}];
var client = new Client(kafkaConn);
var payloads = [ { topic: topics, partition : 0}];
var options = {
    groupId: 'kafka-node-group',
// Auto commit config
    autoCommit: true,
    autoCommitMsgCount: 100,
    autoCommitIntervalMs: 5000,
// Fetch message config
    fetchMaxWaitMs: 100,
    fetchMinBytes: 1,
    fetchMaxBytes: 1024 * 10,
};
var consumer = new HighLevelConsumer(client, payloads, options);

consumer.on('message', function (message) {
    console.log('TEST',this.id, message);
});
```

error

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
 TopicsNotExistError: The topic(s) [object Object] do not exist
    at new TopicsNotExistError (C:\uilogging\node_modules\kafka-node\lib\errors\
TopicsNotExistError.js:11:11)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am doing a similar project where i have a Kafka producer on its own server and am using Kafka-Node as a consumer for my application. I am fairly new to Kafka-Node, and don't have much experience with it, but i can try to share some of the insights i have found.

I believe your problem is literally that your topic doesn't exist.

#### 1. How can i make sure Kafka connection is established?

If your connection wasn't established, i don't think it would move on to say the topic doesn't exist. When i type in a topic that doesn't exist and i type a random ip for my Kafka producer, nothing errors out. But when i point to the correct ip, and an still have incorrect topic, i get the same error you see.

#### 2. This code is working for my application

```
var kafka = require('kafka-node');
var Consumer = kafka.Consumer,
    // The client specifies the ip of the Kafka producer and uses
    // the zookeeper port 2181
    client = new kafka.Client("<ip to producer>:2181"),
    // The consumer object specifies the client and topic(s) it subscribes to
    consumer = new Consumer(
        client, [ { topic: 'myTopic', partition: 0 } ], { autoCommit: false });

consumer.on('message', function (message) {
    // grab the main content from the Kafka message
    var data = JSON.parse(message.value);
    console.log(data);
});
```

Hopefully this doesn't find you too late.

Comment: Thanks it helped me to understand!

Answer (score 0):

If you need this for debugging/development purposes then just add the following imports (the following code is in ES6 format) and it should console.log out a message when the connection is established or if there were any failure messages:

```
this.kafkaLogging = require('kafka-node/logging');
this.kafkaLogging.setLoggerProvider(this.getLoggerProvider);

...

getLoggerProvider() {
    return {
        debug: console.log.bind(console),
        info : console.log.bind(console),
        warn : console.log.bind(console),
        error: console.log.bind(console)
    };
}
```